# Scroll to anchor id within iframe

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have an iframe in which i want to scroll to a specific anchor. I have used with no luck -

```
window.scrollTo(-37, 718);
```

Also have just tried

```
function goToByScroll(id) {
var new_position = getDocument().getElementById(id)
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: new_position.offsetTop }, 'slow');
}
```

Please help.